# Reflect Type.Field() order

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect

I can't seem to find it in documentation, is there any guarantee that the order from the fields will match the order declared in the struct? I know it seems like it would logically (due to memory layout),and it seems to perform this way too, but just making sure. I don't want code to break later on if this isn't a guarantee.

For example, if I had

```
type Foo struct {
    bar    string `tag:"bar"`
    baz    string `tag:"baz"`
    barbaz string `tag:"barbaz"`
}
```

and I ran this code:

```
var c Foo
t := reflect.TypeOf(c)
nf := t.NumField()

tags := make([]string, nf)

for f := 0; f < nf; f++ {
    tags[f] = t.Field(f).Tag.Get("tag")
}
```

Would `tags` be guaranteed to be `["bar", "baz", "barbaz"]`?

Comment: Would [Value.FieldByName](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) help in your case?

Comment: I just wanted the tag names for something, it was more me being a lazy programmer and trying to do a little less coding (which always turns into a ton more work it seems). I don't know if I am going to stick to that method anymore, now I am just kinda interested in the answer.

Comment: Even though GC (the standard Go compiler) and GCCGO don't reoder struct fields, I wouldn't rely on any ordering. There are no express guarantees in the documentation.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question but how do you know they don't reorder struct fields? Also (with the risk of asking too much in a comment) would it ever be considered advantageous for them to do so? I don't know much about compiler design.

Comment: It can be advantageous if you can achieve memory alignment by just reordering the fields instead of adding padding in between them.

Comment: Do you want to add your first comment as an answer so people at least know they can get some info out of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though GC (the standard Go compiler) and GCCGO don't reoder struct fields today, I wouldn't rely on any ordering. There are no express guarantees in the documentation. This might be done in a future version of either compiler.

Field reordering is a technique used to memory-align fields inside of a struct without resorting to padding (unnecessarily inflating the struct's memory representation). You can read about it in the following question:

[Why can't C compilers rearrange struct members to eliminate alignment padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486364/why-cant-c-compilers-rearrange-struct-members-to-eliminate-alignment-padding)

Answer (score 10):

I asked on golang-nuts about this, and got [an answer from Ian Lance Taylor](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/_he7g1TL0K8/8BBCFB0tCgAJ) confirming it's declaration order, and will not change.

> It's the order in which the fields appear in the struct declaration.
> It's not going to change. If you find a case where it is *not* the
> order in the declaration, please file a bug. Thanks.