# sizeof structure not expected in C as compiler does not add padding

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

First up, I tried to go through the existing threads in stackoverflow regarding my question. Atleast, I was not able to find a thread which talks about my issue. 
I am executing the following code for a 32 bit machine through

```
gcc -m32 -o size32 size.c
```

To the contrary, I find that the compiler is not adding the extra padding.  I have not added the **attribute** flag. So I expect the compiler to pad extra bytes. Here is my issue.

```
struct s{
    char c;
    int i;
    double d;
    void *p;
};

    struct s temp;
    void *q;
    double d1=10;

    printf("size of struct = %d sizeof q = %d sizeof double = %d\n",sizeof(temp),sizeof(q),sizeof(d1));
```

The output was
size of **struct = 20** sizeof q = 4 sizeof double = 8

This is my calculation. char(1 byte) + 3 bytes padding + int(4 bytes) + double(8 bytes) + (void*)(4 bytes) which is equal to 20 bytes plus 4 bytes due to the longest member alignment rule **( here double is 8 bytes, so struct should be aligned on a 8 byte boundary )** which finally sums to 24 bytes. So total size should be 24 bytes. Why is it showing only 20 bytes?

Thanks

Chid

Comment: doubles only need to be 4 byte aligned, even though they are 8 bytes in size.

Comment: On linux it is 4-byte aligned, 8-byte with -malign-double compile time option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, unless you pass `-malign-double` to the compiler, doubles are only aligned at 4 byte boundaries, so the struct will not require extra padding.

See documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.5/g77/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: I doubt that that applies to Linux in general; I'd expect it to depend on the target CPU and its ABI.

Comment: Yes, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11110283/233201) for a complete discussion of when double is aligned 4 vs. 8 bytes.