# Unexpected offsets of C++ struct members

Tags: c++

I'm curious about the offsets of C++ struct members when the members are of mixed types. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
struct S {
    char c0;
    char carray[10];
    char c1;
    double d1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << "offset of char   c0 = " << offsetof(S, c0) << '\n'
        << "offset of double carray = " << offsetof(S, carray) << '\n'
        << "offset of double c1 = " << offsetof(S, c1) << '\n'
        << "offset of double d1 = " << offsetof(S, d1) << '\n';
}
```

The output is the following:

```
offset of char   c0 = 0                                                                                                                                       
offset of double carray = 1                                                                                                                                   
offset of double c1 = 11                                                                                                                                      
offset of double d1 = 16
```

The offsets for `c0`, `carray`, and `c1` are all easily understandable. I'm curious about `d1`. Why does it have an offset of 16 instead of the expected value of 12? It looks like it goes through some offset alignment.

Comment: Alignment. Look up `alignof`. Doubles would be 8-byte aligned

Comment: See also [Double alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108328/double-alignment).

Comment: alignment is why it's always recommended to put fields from large to small

Comment: Why do you output `"offset of double carray = "` and `"offset of double c1 = "` when their declarations are `char carray[10]` and `char c1`?

Answer (score 0):

Compilers often align data to 4, 8 or 16 bytes for performance reasons or because of requirements imposed by the CPU.  The C++ standard gives them great leeway in this regard.

`double` is often at a `sizeof(double)` aligned memory address for these reasons.

You can use the `alignof` operator to check the alignment of a particular object.

If the tightest possible packing, with no wasted space, is required for some reason, most compilers have custom keywords or attributes to request this instead of the usual alignment.

Comment: Note that tightest possible packing may break on the architectures for which the alignment is required, not merely beneficial for better performance. It's also typically dependent on non-portable syntax to request the packing. If you want a portable solution, just lay out the struct definition from most aligned to least aligned types, e.g. in this case, put `double d1;` first.